# Remove specific tags if are inside specific tag

Tags: html, ruby, regex, html-parsing

I have a problem, and I have to find the fast solution.

I want to remove `br` and `p` tags inside all "tables" but not outside.

For ex.

Initial html document:

```
...
<p>Hello</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Text example <br>continues...</p></td>
    <td><p>Text example <br>continues...</p></td>
    <td><p>Text example <br>continues...</p></td>
    <td><p>Text example <br>continues...</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>Bye<br></p>
<p>Bye<br></p>
...
```

My objective:

```
...
<p>Hello</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Text example continues...</td>
    <td>Text example continues...</td>
    <td>Text example continues...</td>
    <td>Text example continues...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>Bye<br></p>
<p>Bye<br></p>
...
```

Now, thats is my method to clean:

```
loop do
  if html.match(/<table>(.*?)(<\/?(p|br)*?>)(.*?)<\/table>/) != nil
    html = html.gsub(/<table>(.*?)(<\/?(p|br)*?>)(.*?)<\/table>/,'<table>\1 \4</table>')
  else
    break
  end
end
```

That works great, but the problem is, I have 1xxx documents and every one have about 1000 lines... and takes 1-3 hours every one. ((1-3 hours)*(thousands documents)) = ¡pain!

I'm looking to do it with Sanitize or other method, but for now... I don't find the way.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you in advance!
Manu

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/438992 In other words, use an actual HTML parser.

Comment: ^ To add to the above, look into using `Nokogiri` for this.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/ruby for examples of how to properly parse HTML with Ruby modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [**Nokogiri**](http://nokogiri.org/):

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse <<-_HTML_
<p>Hello</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Text example <br>continues...</p></td>
    <td><p>Text example <br>continues...</p></td>
    <td><p>Text example <br>continues...</p></td>
    <td><p>Text example <br>continues...</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>Bye<br></p>
<p>Bye<br></p>
_HTML_

doc.xpath("//table/tr/td/p").each do |el|
  el.replace(el.text)
end

puts doc.to_html
```

***Output:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<p>Hello</p>
<table><tr>
<td>Text example continues...</td>
    <td>Text example continues...</td>
    <td>Text example continues...</td>
    <td>Text example continues...</td>
  </tr></table>
<p>Bye<br></p>
<p>Bye<br></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The paragraph tags also needed to be removed from the table.

Comment: Amazing! I will try that now! I tell you something! Thanks!

Comment: Works! Thank you very much @Babai !! And 10000% fast than my method :)